# How to set Guide's Title in amChart?

Tags: graph, amcharts

I am using bundle chart ( amChart ) of line area type. To display text inside the plot area, I am using the following:

`<title>`Reach: 256 `</title>`

The dashed line option is also enabled with start_value & end_value. The problem is that the dashed line also strikes through the title ( i.e. Reach: 256 ). Is it possible to give margin to line so that it may not strike through/cut the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer:

Remove `<end_date>` tag and use start_value tag only.